# How does $f^{-1}(\{-\infty, \infty\}) = \emptyset$ follow from the fact that $f$ is a real-valued function?

Tags: measure-theory

First are relevant definitions from textbook $\textbf{ Analysis III}$ by Amann.

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a complete, $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E,|\cdot|)$ a Banach space.
>
> We say $f \in E^{X}$ is $\mu$-simple if $f(X)$ is finite, $f^{-1}(e) \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $e \in E,$ and $\mu\left(f^{-1}(E \backslash\{0\})\right)<\infty .$ We denote by $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ the set of all $\mu$-simple functions.
>
> A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mu$-measurable if there is a sequence $\left(f_{j}\right)$ in $\mathcal{S}(X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_{j} \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere as $j \rightarrow \infty$.
>
> A function $f \in E^{X}$ is said to be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable if the inverse images of open sets of $E$ under $f$ are measurable, that is, if $f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}_{E}\right) \subset \mathcal{A},$ where $\mathcal{T}_{E}$ is the norm topology on $E .$ If there is a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $f\left(N^{c}\right)$ is separable, we say $f$ is $\mu$ -almost separable valued.

Then the authors present measurable $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions:

> [image]

Could you please explain how the authors get $f^{-1}(\{-\infty, \infty\}) = \emptyset$ from the fact that $f$ is a real-valued function?

Is it $f^{-1}(-\infty) = f^{-1}(+\infty) := \emptyset$ and thus $f^{-1}(\{-\infty, \infty\}) = f^{-1}(-\infty) \cup f^{-1}(+\infty) = \emptyset$? If so, $f(\emptyset) = -\infty$ and $f(\emptyset) = +\infty$, which contradicts the definition of a function.

Comment: it is not obvious? Because $f$ is real valued then there is no $x\in X $ such that $f(x)\in\{-\infty ,\infty \}$

Comment: Thank you @Masacroso! I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-\infty \not \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\infty \not \in \Bbb{R}$, so neither is in the image of $f$.